# A standalone ng-for in angular 2?

Tags: angular

Is it possible to have an ng-for not attached to any element?

For example lets say I have a list of foo objects which themself contains bars. Then I want to iterate through both the foos and bars and not have them nested.

Many other frameworks support it in a (hypothetical) fashion like this:

```
<table>
{% for foo in foos %}
  <tr>first level tr</tr>
  {% for bar in foo.bars %}
    <tr>same level as above tr</tr>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

But in angular, you do have to attached the ng-for to an actual element or can you make something as similar to above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news: it's possible. Bad news: for now you must use [canonical form](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.45/modules/angular2/docs/core/01_templates.md#inline-templates) of [*ng-for](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/NgFor-class.html) to achieve this:

```html
<template ng-for #foo [ng-for-of]="foos">
  Put your template here
</template>
```

Later you may write it like (see [this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4355)):

```html
<template *ng-for="#foo from foos">
  Put your template here
</template>
```

but it's not implemented yet.

So, for now your example looks like (see [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gwGKNQhtrnyEVgsTFeHU?p=preview)):

```js
import {Component, NgFor} from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [NgFor],
  template: `
    <table>
      <template ng-for #foo [ng-for-of]="foos">
        <tr><td>first level tr</td></tr>
        <template ng-for #bar [ng-for-of]="foo.bars">
          <tr><td>same level as above tr</td></tr>
        </template>
      </template>
    </table>
  `
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.foos = [
      { bars: ['bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3'] },
      { bars: ['some1', 'some2', 'some3'] }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Care, right now its changed:

```html
SELECTORS [ngFor][ngForOf]
<template ngFor #item [ngForOf]="items" #i="index"><li>...</li></template>
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgFor-directive.html